# Como hago un substr pero con caracteres?

Tags: php, substr

Hola quiero hacer un substr pero con caracteres a mi string ósea por ejemplo:

```
 $string = "%hola que tal/ todo good?";
```

lo que quiero es mostrar el "hola que tal" por los caracteres ahí alguna función que haga eso??

Comment: Es decir, querés hacer un `substr` (o lo equivalente) de lo que hay entre `%` y `/` (en este caso).

Comment: Te refieres a esto? https://3v4l.org/aTvSh#v8.1.1

Comment: no eso no es a lo que me refiero, lo que pregunto es si ahí alguna función que haga eso de separar por caracteres ósea que los limites sean esos caracteres

Comment: Entonces te refieres al Explode https://3v4l.org/4q9SY#v8.1.1

Comment: si es verdad justo lo encontré en una pagina igual se puede hacer que traiga el string que esta dentro de esos caracteres??

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste por favor, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es combinar `substr` y `preg_match` de este modo:

```php
$string = '%hola que tal/ todo good?';
$pattern = '/%.*\//i';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $coincidencias);
$cadena = substr($coincidencias[0], 1, -1);
echo $cadena;
```

**Explicación línea a línea:**

- En la primera definimos el `string` a tratar

```php
$string = '%hola que tal/ todo good?';
```

- En la segunda la **expresión regular** que va a encontrar todo lo que hay encerrado entre estos dos delimitadores:  `%` y `/`

```php
$pattern = '/%.*\//i';
```

- En la siguiente realizamos una búsqueda de `$pattern` en `$string`, y lo almacenamos en el array de salida `$coincidencias`

```php
preg_match($pattern, $string, $coincidencias);
```

- Ahora necesitamos eliminar el primer y el último caracter del string coincidente almacenado en `$coincidencias[0]` (en este caso solo hay uno y por eso accedemos a el mediante su índice de array):

```php
$cadena = substr($coincidencias[0], 1, -1);
```

- Mostramos el resultado:

```php
echo $cadena;
```

que teóricamente seria `hola que tal` en este caso concreto.

O sea, respondiendo a tu pregunta en los comentarios, la función que buscas podria ser `preg_match` (hay otras que tambien trabajan con expresiones regulares pero esta es la más habitual).

Comment: excelente explicación y muy ejemplo , la verdad lo logre con explode pero eso también sirve :0